# How to check user based events on fabric

Tags: google-fabric

Our requirement is for specific user we need to check what events he performed.

Lets say for user John we need to check if he able to find out filter feature from app etc.

On Fabric I can see its shows event and unique users, but its not showing their username, userid etc.

So is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. With the Fabric dashboard, there is not a way to track a user across crashes and events. You can however, add custom logs, keys and user identifiers to exceptions or logged errors and can then search on those values.

Comment: Thanks Mike, we would love to see this feature in next releases. Right now we are using fabric for all our crash analytics and logging needs, only if you peoples can make it perfect for event analytics, we will not need to search for other options.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's not on our immediate roadmap to add in, but I'll chat with the team about it.